# How to make an easy-to-use script/file which finds and rotates horizontal images on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, batch, script, images, rotate

If I have a folder with hundreds of images, and some are wider than they are tall, I'd like to be able to easily rotate the wide images so everything is vertical. Currently I have to skim through the thumbnails and manually flip all the horizontal images.

I've seen "shell scripts" and "imagemagick" mentioned in regards to this, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to use these on Windows 7. How can I make something like a batch file which I can easily place in the folder and have it do everything for me?

Comment: Are your images jpeg, and are you trying to rotate them selectively to be correctly upright?

Comment: Yes, they're JPEGs. If by "selectively" you mean selecting only the ones I want (the wider ones), then that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Processing .jpg (rotating) can degrade them so best off starting with not overwriting.

[Download Imagemagick for Windows](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

From a batch file.  Do not overwrite originals.  Rotate 90 degrees clockwise:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
md "path-to-parent-folder-with-double-quotes-if-there-is-a-space-in-the-path\rotated\"
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b "path-to-parent-folder-with-double-quotes-if-there-is-a-space-in-the-path\*.jpg"') do "path-to-imagemagick\convert.exe" "path-to-parent-folder-with-double-quotes-if-there-is-a-space-in-the-path\%%x" -rotate "90>" "path-to-parent-folder-with-double-quotes-if-there-is-a-space-in-the-path\rotated\%%x"
exit /b
```

For example:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
md "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\New folder\rotated\"
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\new folder\*.jpg"') do "%ProgramFiles%\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\new folder\%%x" -rotate "90>" "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\new folder\rotated\%%x"
exit /b
```

From a batch file.  Overwrite originals. Rotate 90 degrees clockwise:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b "path-to-parent-folder-with-double-quotes-if-there-is-a-space-in-the-path\*.jpg"') do "path-to-imagemagick\convert.exe" "path-to-parent-folder-with-double-quotes-if-there-is-a-space-in-the-path\%%x" -rotate "90>" "path-to-parent-folder-with-double-quotes-if-there-is-a-space-in-the-path\%%x"
exit /b
```

For example:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\new folder\*.jpg"') do "%ProgramFiles%\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\new folder\%%x" -rotate "90>" "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\new folder\rotated\%%x"
exit /b
```

A windows shortcut that rotates 90 degrees clockwise and overwrites every .jpg in the directory it is started in:

```
   cmd /c for /f "tokens=*" %x in ('dir /b *.jpg') do "%ProgramFiles%\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe" "%x" -rotate "90>" "%x"
```

A windows shortcut that rotates 90 degrees clockwise and overwrites every .jpg in the directory it is started in and in all the subdirectories:

```
   cmd /c for /f "tokens=*" %x in ('dir /b /s *.jpg') do "%ProgramFiles%\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16\convert.exe" "%x" -rotate "90>" "%x"
```

[image: Start in:]

rotate 90 degress clockwise

```
-rotate "90>"
```

rotate 90 degress counterclockwise

```
-rotate "-90>"
```

Apply Path image rotation (using shear operations) to the image.
Use > to rotate the image only if its width exceeds the height. < rotates the image only if its width is less than the height. For example, if you specify -rotate "-90>" and the image size is 480x640, the image is not rotated. However, if the image is 640x480, it is rotated by -90 degrees. If you use > or <, enclose it in quotation marks to prevent it from being misinterpreted as a file redirection.
Empty triangles in the corners, left over from rotating the image, are filled with the background color. The above is from [here.](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#rotate)

See also the [-distort](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#distort) operator and specifically the 'ScaleRotateTranslate' distort method.

For more info about using imagemagick command line processing see [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php)